# How to re-queue celery task until after lock is released

Tags: redis, celery

I have a number of celery tasks that currently use a non-blocking redis lock to ensure atomic edits of a cluster of db tables for a particular user. The timing of the tasks is unpredictable and the frequency is high but sporadic. For example some are triggered by web hooks, other by user interaction.

Right now I am using `autoretry_for` and `retry_backoff` to respond to failures to acquire the non-blocking lock. This is sub-optimal since it leaves lots of idle time once the lock has been released. I can't use a blocking lock because I need to let other tasks that don't require the lock to still run.

What I need is a way to re-run *any* tasks that failed to acquire the non-blocking lock as soon as possible after the lock is released. It doesn't matter if some handful of non-locking tasks are run in the meantime, I just need the tasks that failed to acquire to run reasonably soon but certainly without idle time.

How can this be done? It's like I want to add the tasks to some kind of global celery `chain`, but post-hoc, and then fire any waiting chains every time the non-blocking lock is released. Or something like that. Which user each tasks are crunching is calculated *from* the task's arguments, it is not passed in through the arguments (so key-based queues won't work).